# gson handle: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: android, gson, deserialization, retrofit

I am using Retrofit and `Gson` to make API calls. I have a problem with responses from server. For some attributes it is sending empty  `JSONArray` instead of null `JSONObject`. e.g.:

in normal situation:

```
  {
    "pagination": { 
      "links": {
        "next": "http://api.com/nextlink"
      } 
    }
  }
```

but sometimes when the "links" is empty, the server sends me this:

```
  {
    "pagination": { 
      "links": []
    }
  }
```

which cause `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY`.

I know that I can handle it with using custom `JsonDeserializer` for object "Pagination" and `registerTypeAdapter` when creating `GsonBuilder`.

But my question is: It is possible to handle this cases in general for all responses? I don't have access to API so I cannot change it and I don't know for which attributes I can get empty `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject` that is expected.

Thank you.

Comment: [Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but Was BEGIN_OBJECT](http://sachinpatil.com/blog/2012/07/03/gson/) - similar problem with general solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to check  if it is an object or not

```
yourJson.get("links").isJsonObject()
```

check these methods

```
isJsonArray()
isJsonObject()
isJsonNull()
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, Thank you for your response. But this is not answer to my question. I wrote that I can handle it for this case (i.e. for object Pagination). But I am looking for a solution, that will be working in general for all responses. The Problem is, that I don't know all situations, where the attribute can have empty JSONArray [] instead of JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSONTokener to get normal Object after check it with instanceof function, try bellow:

```
String jsonData =  "{...}"; //your json data string
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(jsonData);
    try {
        Object parsedObj = tokener.nextValue();
        if (parsedObj instanceof JSONObject) {

               //do something here
        }else if (parsedObj instanceof JSONArray){
             //do something here
        }
     }catch(Exception ex){}
```

Read more here [enter link description here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/org.json.JSONTokener)